# Can we replace `if (!x) x=true` with `x=true` directly?

Tags: c++

I am doing some refactoring work and came across such a piece of code:

```
bool x = false;

...// maybe some logical work would change the value of x.

if (!x) {
  x = true;
}
```

So, I am curious whether I can do such a replacement:

```
x = true;
```

As you can see, I assign x to true directly, which may reduce the number of instructions in the CPU, but I am not sure if there are any hidden dangers.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I assume the value of `x` is used before the assignment? Otherwise it seems rather useless.

Comment: The answer is yes. because if x=false x will be equal to true

Comment: The latter always does cache invalidation. On a multiprocessor CPU that may impact performance negatively.

Comment: Another case is if `bool` is replaced with a structure type with `operator=` and `operator bool` both overloaded. If either have side effects, it might not have the same effect as just simply assigning. This is a super edge case of course, just wanted to be complete.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: According to C++ rules, the two fragments have the same meaning, so you can't assume one invalidates caches and the other doesn't.

Comment: @MSalters - I can, because real life hardware actually works like that. Does "cache coherence" mean nothing to you? But you are welcome to point out where the abstract machine requires the same exact cache behaviour.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: I know how real hardware works, for a pretty decent set of architectures . C++ semantics differ from hardware semantics, though. The C++ abstract machine does not have "cache coherence". The compiler is free to insert or elide non-volatile reads, because these are utterly irrelevant to the C++ abstract machine. Any program that relies on a particular hardware behavior will be subject to Unspecified Behavior.

Comment: @MSalters - There is plenty of programs being written that depend on knowing the hardware they run on. Unless you know where the OP's code is contained (you like to assume no synchronisation primitives, but you have *no way* of *knowing*), you can't claim their performance will be unaffected. Unconditionally dirtying a cache line *can very well* have an effect. The observable behavior of the abstract machine is the same either way in that case and I wasn't referring to it *at all*. Some serious intentional obtusness is required to go about "correcting" what I wasn't even saying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x = true;` is clearer than `if (!x) { x = true; }`.

From performance point of view, former avoids branching, whereas the later doesn't touch to "cacheline" (in one case).

And compiler might change one to another with as-is rule anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your exact context of course, but if the purpose here after that block is to have `x` be equal to `true`, then `x = true;` is the same (and much more readable).

Answer (score -1):

> Can we replace `if (!x) x=true` with `x=true` directly?

If the type of `x` is `bool` such as in the example, then yes. For other types there may be a difference.